# passing tab separated entries to readarray

Tags: shell, array

Obviously I'm not doing it right, but I think the intended outcome is clear (`${#arr[@]}`=3)

```
$ readarray -d "\t" arr < <(printf "%s\t%s\t%s" "x" "y" "z"); echo "${#arr[@]}"
> 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shell doesn't know that `\t` should be a tab. It is looking for a literal `\` followed by a `t` (ignoring the latter as delimiters can only be single bytes (not even characters)):

```
$ readarray -d "\t" arr < <(printf %s 'x\ty\tz'); echo "${#arr[@]}"
3
$ typeset -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="x\\" [1]="ty\\" [2]="tz")
```

For actual tabs, you need to escape like this:

```
$ readarray -d $'\t' arr < <(printf "%s\t%s\t%s" "x" "y" "z"); echo "${#arr[@]}"
3
```

Note that your third value above is not delimited. It's fine here because it's not empty, but had it been empty, you'd have gotten:

```
$ readarray -d $'\t' arr < <(printf "%s\t%s\t%s" "x" "y" ""); echo "${#arr[@]}"
2
```

To allow any value (that doesn't contain TAB nor NUL characters) including empty ones, you'd want to make sure they are delimited with:

```
printf '%s\t' "$val1" "$val2" "$val3"
```

Same as:

```
printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t' "$val1" "$val2" "$val3"
```

You may also want to remove the delimiters from the array elements with `readarray`'s `-t` option.

Comment: (@stephane-chazelas, thanks for the edit) And using pipe?

Comment: @Erwann, not sure what you mean, but which delimiter you use doesn't matter. `readarray -d x` is to process *delimited* values. It's typically used with newline or NUL delimiters to read lines or NUL-delimited records (like the output of `find -print0`) into an array.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I mean swapping the order of `readarray` and `printf`, with a pipe connecting the two.

Comment: @Erwann, `printf | readarray` would be the natural way to do it, but because by default bash runs pipeline components in subshells, `readarray < <(printf)` is the common work-around for that. In any case, even with `shopt -s lastpipe` which causes the rightmost pipeline component not to run in a subshell (for non-interactive shells only), that won't make a functional difference.

Comment: @terdon, sorry I didn't originally intend to make such an extensive edit. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Well actually, this works. `$ printf "%s\t" "x" "y" "z" | { readarray -d $'\t' arr; echo "${#arr[@]}"; }`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas mind? Not at all! Your edit is nothing but a clear improvement, thank you! I had originally (and stupidly) assumed that the `\t` was becoming a `t` and thought that `xtytz` would work and when I saw that didn't, I naively assumed it was taking both instead of testing with a `\ ` alone.

Comment: @Erwann, yes, because that `echo` is run in the same subshell that is running `readarray`, but after that, your array is lost as the subshell where it is defined returns.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas indeed, it is based on your previous comment "would be the natural way...common work-around". It may suffice for limited needs. Otherwise I suppose [exporting the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21941473/9243116)